What is this window pane and how do I remove it?
I have double-hung windows that are original (1960s). Outside of the windows themselves there are 3 additional tracks. Of those 3 tracks, the outer 2 have solid panes, the inner one has a screen. How do I get the outermost pane out? Half of the glass broke out and I want to replace it.
Picture: https://imgur.com/a/CGRVVyk

It's extra dicey because I can lift this pane up, but it just falls right back down. The other pane, and the screen, both have spring-loaded tabs that keep them up, but not this one.
Also, what do you call these "extra windows"? I've heard of storm windows, but these don't look like what googling "storm windows" brings up. I suspect I wasn't finding answers because I'm not searching for the right term.
1st time homeowner and I've learned a lot from this forum -- thanks, everyone.

"Aluminum Storm Windows" or "Triple-track aluminum storm windows" are the common terms beyond simply "storm windows" in describing what you have.

Got it -- thanks

Yours look a bit different than most of the ones I've seen, which have more obvious latches on all 3 sliders, but begin by pulling in the tabs on the screen all the way, to see if the bottom with the tabs will then come out of the track towards the inside (at which point you can pull it out flat and lift one side of the top to release that from the track.) Some may have a small gap in the track you have to line up with. If that works, repeat with the second pane.
The outermost pane should be on the top half of the window (where it would normally stay), as the brush weatherstripping on its bottom shows. That's to seal against the middle pane sliding past it, whcih won't happen with it sitting on the bottom. Less rain gets in that way. While it does not have handles for easy manipulation, (or they were broken off) it may have some place you can stick a tool or nail in to to release similar latches and pull the bottom in. Or they might be on its top, instead. You could lift it a few inches and add a picture close-up of the corner for more insight.

Ah, thanks, I think this put me on the right track.
I pulled the screen tabs as suggested and yes, I got it to pop out. Your note that the panel should be on top (and why, which was super helpful) made me play with it more and I discovered smaller tabs hidden under the brush weatherstripping of the broken pane. I can't get them to pop out like the screen, but I suspect they need some lubricant so I'm off to give that a shot. Much appreciated.

You do need the middle pane out before you try to pull the outermost pane, too.

In my experience with aluminum storm windows, which may not be the same design: release the bottom tabs, which will allow the window to tilt inward until it is horizontal. Then raise or lower one side of the frame to gain space to disengage the fixed top tabs
